# C++ Operator Precedence while using vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector

Why does the next program prints 1 instead of 4?

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(4);
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
int n = *(it++);
std::cout << n;
```

Comment: If your intention is to increment the `iterator` first, and then assess its value, you should do a preincrement.  I.e. `int n = *++it;`

Answer (score 2):

The pre/post increment operator is part of an *expression* that evaluates to a value (and has a side effect of changing the variable being incremented.)

Evaluation of prefix increment (++i) is `increment variable, return new value`

Evaluation of postfix increment (i++) is `increment variable, return original value`

Comment: @Casperon It would be a good idea to mark this answer as accepted to help future folk with the same question.